# Как войти на сайт с помощью Requests?

Tags: python, cookie, auth, requests

Нужно с помощью requests авторизоваться на сайте https://ctr.ru/ и получить данные со страниц типа https://ctr.ru/?event=detail&i=983 (страница доступна только для авторизованных пользователей). Пытаюсь вытащить cookie с Google Chrome (в браузере я авторизован):

```
import browser_cookie3
import requests
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
r = requests.get('https://ctr.ru/?event=detail&i=983', cookies=cj)
```

Но requests получает страницу https://ctr.ru/, сайт перенаправляет неавторизованных пользователей. Предполагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что протокол сайта HTTPS. Что ещё можно сделать для авторизации? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Проанализировал, что отправляется на сайт при авторизации, и оказалось, что кроме логина и пароля на сайт отправляется параметр a_event со значением _login. Этот код заработал (программа авторизуется и заходит на страницы, доступные только для авторизованных пользователей):

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
data = {'user_login': 'login', 'user_pass': 'password', 'a_event': '_login'}
url = 'https://ctr.ru/'
r = s.post(url, data=data)
r = requests.get('https://ctr.ru/?event=detail&i=984', cookies=s.cookies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сохранить cookies используй Session(), например:

```
import requests

username = 'user'
password = 'password'

url = 'https://www.example.com'
sess = requests.Session()
sess.verify = False

resp = sess.post(url + '/login', data={'username': username, 'password': password})
resp.raise_for_status()

resp = sess.get(url + '/index.html')
resp.raise_for_status()

print(resp)
```

Comment: Я знаю про сессии, я вообще не могу на сайте авторизоваться. Отправляю POST-запрос с логином и паролем на https://ctr.ru/#modal_form_enter (форма входа, других страниц для входа нет), ничего не меняется. Вопрос состоит именно в том, как авторизоваться на сайте?

Comment: Ну, не знаю, попробуй сначала сделать реквест index.html, может оно в этот момент выставляет session cookie, перед тем как авторизовать пользователя.

Comment: Нет, не получается, вообще такой страницы нет. `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://www.ctr.ru/index.html`

Comment: Вижу ответ, молодца! :)